# file_get_contents returns PHP code

Tags: php, file-get-contents

When I use `file_get_contents()` function on a local file, the result contains php code, though I need HTML only.

Content of the file being read:

```
<?php echo '<p>Hello</p>';?>
```

And the result of file_get_contents called from a different file located in the same folder:

```
<?php echo file_get_contents('test.php'); //returns the following: string(31) "Hello'; ?>"
```

If I read a file from an external server, it returns HTML - as I would expect. So the question is: how do I get HTML output from the local file? Thank you all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the files url (not filepath), so it is processed by the server eg:

```
echo file_get_contents('http://website.com/test.php');
```

However include/require would be better, eg:

```
include 'test.php';
```

Answer (score 4):

`file_get_contents()` only reads the plain file contents, as it's name suggests.

If you want the PHP interpreted, wou will have to `include()` it.

The according documentation can be found here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Answer (score 0):

brainbowler alredy answered is pretty well. Additionally is suggest you to read the following docs:

- https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.include.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.require.php.

The PHP functions **include** and **require** are much alike and will do what you are trying to achive (they handle the include paths differently tough). There are also **include_once** and **require_once** which will also include and execute your script (and output the generated/contained HTML). But only once. They are useful if you haver your include statement in a loop or whatever and dont want it to load 42 times but only once.

Looks like you need to spend some more time on the basics (we all did). ;)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I completely agree on the need to spend more time learning the language.